# TGIF tutorial or manual

Tags: vector-drawings

Does anyone know where I can find a complete tutorial or manual for TGIF? The one I have found is difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [Tgif FAQ](http://bourbon.usc.edu/tgif/faq/) already? If you find difficult to read, you should start with the introduction first; There is an introduction found via FAQ, partially quoted as below.

> **Tgif's man pages are very hard to understand. Is there something more introductory for a tgif beginner?**
>
> Daan Reuhman wrote a LaTeX document called tgifintro. [...]
>
> ```
>    gunzip -c tgifintro-1.0.1.tar.gz | tar xvf -
>    cd tgifintro-1.0.1
>    make
>    gv tgifintro.ps
> ```
>
> Running make above runs latex and dvips.
>
> A gzipped PostScript (58,987 bytes) and a PDF (106,411 bytes) versions are also available.

Visit [this introduction](http://bourbon.usc.edu/tgif/faq/intro.html) page for the link to gzipped PostScript and PDF files.